# using getElementsByTagName with nav tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I am trying to collapse all nav bars simultaneously using this code, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```html
var toggleOffAll = function() {
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
 var j;
 for (j = 0; j < j.length; j++){
  
 x[j].style.display='none';
 };
  };
```

Comment: Your for loop isn't executing because `j.length` is undefined.

Comment: I will suggest to always debug your javascript, a simple debug run should have pointed that `j.length` was not returning any value because `j` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Your current `for loop` is looping `0` times instead of looping `"n"` times where `n` is the number of nav elements that you have.

Change this:

```
j < j.length;
```

To this:

```
j < x.length;
```

---

If you are not concerned with IE11 compatibility, you can use the **[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method instead like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav').forEach(function(e){
    e.style.display='none';
})
```

---

Or if you are open to using *JavaScript ES6+*, you can further shorten the above code to a single line by using an *arrow function* instead like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav').forEach(e=>e.style.display='none');
```

---

**N.B.** If you are planning to go with the ES6+ approach, you will need to use a JavaScript compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert your ES6+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript on production so it will support current and older browsers or environments.

Answer (score -3):

jQuery would be much easier:

```
$('nav').css("display", "none");
```

Comment: There is no indication the OP uses or wants to use jQuery.